# Idiomatic way in kotlin to transform/append to a list?

Tags: kotlin

Say I'm trying to implement some function:

```
private fun List<Int>.padWithIndices(newLength: Int): List<Int>
```

It takes a list and returns a list, with some appended values, where for each new value this[i] = i.

Kotlin gives us tons of nice ways to append to lists, to concatenate two different lists, to create mutable lists, etc. So many that I don't know which is best in this scenario, and I don't know if there are any hidden pitfalls. This is my original for-loop based solution, are there more efficient/idiomatic solutions?

```
fun List<Int>.padWithIndices(newLength: Int): List<Int> {
    var newList = this
    for (x in size until newLength) {
        newList += x
    }
    return newList
}
```

Comment: My personal suggestion is that a lazy approach would be the most fictional programming style which is considered kotlin idiomatic by my understanding, where the new list is a lazy wrapper around the old and only accesses the original lists element if it actually is asked for. Like a java stream. This assumes the original list is immutable. I can't code right now so this is not a full answer more a suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

While your solution is quite readable, it copies all of the items of the original `List<Int>` on every iteration of the `for`-loop, as `+=` on a `var newList: List<Int>` will create a new list each time. The computational complexity of the worst case is O(n²), which can be improved to O(n).

---

For this particular case when you just want to append a continuous range to a list, a one-line function like this will work:

```
fun List<Int>.padWithIndices(newLength: Int): List<Int> = 
    plus(size until newLength)
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

It calls the [`plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) function on the receiver list, producing a new list with the items from the argument appended.

You can also call `plus` as the [operator `+`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#arithmetic), replacing the line with `this + (size until newLength)`.

---

For use cases with more complex logic for computing the items that you append to the list, you can use the [`List(n) { ... }` factory function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html), which accepts a lambda providing the list items and thus ensures that each list item is only computed once:

```
fun List<Int>.padWithIndices(newLength: Int): List<Int> = 
    List(newLength) { index -> getOrNull(index) ?: index }
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjMxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IlNhbXBsZUlucHV0MSBTYW1wbGVJbnB1dDIiLCJqc0NvZGUiOiIiLCJub25lTWFya2VycyI6dHJ1ZSwidGhlbWUiOiJpZGVhIiwiZm9sZGVkQnV0dG9uIjp0cnVlLCJyZWFkT25seSI6ZmFsc2UsImNvZGUiOiJmdW4gTGlzdDxJbnQ+LnBhZFdpdGhJbmRpY2VzKG5ld0xlbmd0aDogSW50KTogTGlzdDxJbnQ+ID0gXG4gICAgTGlzdChuZXdMZW5ndGgpIHsgaW5kZXggLT4gZ2V0T3JOdWxsKGluZGV4KSA/OiBpbmRleCB9XG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBsaXN0ID0gbGlzdE9mKC0xLCAtMiwgLTMpXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihsaXN0LnBhZFdpdGhJbmRpY2VzKDIpKSAvLyBbLTEsIC0yLCAtM11cbiAgICBwcmludGxuKGxpc3QucGFkV2l0aEluZGljZXMoNikpIC8vIFstMSwgLTIsIC0zLCAzLCA0LCA1XVxufSIsInRvIjoiIiwiZnJvbSI6IiJ9)</sup>

The function [`getOrNull(index)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-null.html) returns the item at the specified index or `null` if the index is out of bounds. The latter is handled by `?: index`.

---

Alternatively, rewrite your solution and use a mutable list inside the function implementation, appending the items to it, then return it as a read-only `List<Int>`:

```
fun List<Int>.padWithIndices(newLength: Int): List<Int> =
    toMutableList().apply {
        addAll(size until newLength)
    }
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

Comment: I'd add use of `plus` as an operator.

Answer (score 0):

That works, but you are appending to the list on the loop, so that may trigger a reallocation in the list.

This is more efficient as the list gets initialized with the right size first:

```
fun List<Int>.padWithIndices(newLength: Int): List<Int> = List(newLength) { index ->
    if (index < size) {
        get(index)
    } else {
        index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
fun List<Int>.padWithIndices(newLength: Int): List<Int> =
  toMutableList().apply { addAll(size until newLength) }
```

Convert initial list to `MutableList<Int>` (backed by ArrayList in JVM), then create `IntRange` from size of copied list until `newLength`, call `MutableList<Int>.addAll(Iterable<Int>)` and finaly downcast to `List<Int>`.